# How to implement from scratch asynchronous single threaded tasks in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, low-level

As far as I know there are four kinds of program executions:

***1)*** Synchronous (one thread):

Synchronous (one thread):

```
1 thread ->   |<---A---->||<----B---------->||<------C----->|
```

***2)*** Synchronous (multi-threaded):

```
thread A -> |<---A---->|   
                        \  
thread B ------------>   ->|<----B---------->|   
                                              \   
thread C ---------------------------------->   ->|<------C----->|
```

***3)*** Asynchronous (one thread):

```
         A-Start ------------------------------------------ A-End   
           | B-Start -----------------------------------------|--- B-End   
           |    |      C-Start ------------------- C-End      |      |   
           |    |       |                           |         |      |
           V    V       V                           V         V      V      
1 thread->|<-A-|<--B---|<-C-|-A-|-C-|--A--|-B-|--C-->|---A---->|--B-->|
```

***4)*** Asynchronous (multi-Threaded):

```
 thread A ->     |<---A---->|
 thread B ----->     |<----B---------->| 
 thread C --------->     |<------C--------->|
```

- Start and end points of tasks A, B, C represented by `<`, `>` characters.
- CPU time slices represented by vertical bars `|`

But the only one that I don't know how to implement from scratch is the ***single threaded asynchronous execution***. I'd like to know how to implement something similar (without threads) in a low level language from 0 like C if its possible.

Comment: One possible way to implement 3 is to have each or A, B and C just do a little bit of work, then return for another "thread" to perform a little bit of work. And so on, until all three have performed all work.

Comment: It's not clear what, exactly, you want but coroutines might fit the bill. There is a short description of the implementation in/for multiple languages, including C in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine

Comment: Looks like thats what I need, I'll do some research and if I can answer the question

Comment: Have a look at libevent.  It's a library for managing async events from a single process.